# sum DataFrame rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like so:

```
     a   b  c  d  e  f
1.   1   5  5  9  2  3
2.   4   7  3  1  4  6
3.   2   3  8  9  2  1 
4.   7   3  1  4  7  11
5.   8   5  4  9  0  3
6.   7   8  4  7  2  1
```

I want to sum up the values for 4 elements of rows and columns  for example. This would give me 1+5+4+7=17
and 5+9+3+1=18 , 2+3+4+6=15 , ...

output

```
       a    b    c
   1.  17   18   15
   2.  18   22   21
   3.  28   27   6
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try numpy's `reshape` and `sum`:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
a.reshape(df.shape[0]//2,2, df.shape[1]//2,2).sum((1,3))
```

Output:

```
array([[17, 18, 15],
       [15, 22, 21],
       [28, 24,  6]])
```

Comment: Was the reshape arbitrary and then you choose the appropriate sum axis? If not, how did you know how to reshape?

Answer (score 6):

Let us try [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```
pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('ijkl->ik',df.values.reshape(3,2,3,2)))
Out[101]: 
    0   1   2
0  17  18  15
1  15  22  21
2  28  24   6
```

Comment: Tried `df.rolling(2,axis=1).sum().iloc[:,1::2].rolling(2).sum().iloc[1::2]` but probably not as efficient as yours and Quang's. Learnt about `einsum` +1